# How to avoid deadlocks during synchronization in Java?

Tags: java, synchronization, deadlock, monitor

In Java, there is a "monitor" synchronization mechanism with the functions "wait", "notify" and "notifyall". It's said that using "notifyall" instead of "notify" can avoid deadlocks efficiently, but I cannot really understand this one. Could anyone help to interpret this sentence?

Comment: You need to learn more about multi-threaded development. Good luck; thread-safety is _hard_.

Comment: Read http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-in-Practice-ebook/dp/B004V9OA84

Comment: Yes, that's what I found. Thanks assylias :) Thank you guys.

Comment: @assylias did you flag this as a duplicate? If you can't I'll do that for you.